# Maths operations in a .cshtml

Tags: javascript

I come from a C/C++ background and I am having trouble doing maths in javascript (index.cshtml file) as cannot cast or do a ToDouble(), nothing seems to work. I cannot get a double or float type to work without error.  I understand that using the var type it understands if a type is an Int or decimal but I cannot get them to add together.
If I try to use the double type I just get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error.
Parameters passed in a 'var' type.

Thank you!

```
function DmsToDeg(d, m, s, c, h)
{
    var t;        
    t = d + (m / 60.0) + (s / 3600) + (c / 360000);

    if (h.toString() == 'S') || (h.toString() == 'W')
        t = -t;

    return t;
}
```

gives a very incorrect answer of:

```
35 44 20 27 S
t is 350.73333333333333330.0055555555555555560.000075
degs is NaN
```

Comment: This question should be `javascript`?

Comment: Meanwhile there is syntax error on your `if` statement. Should be `if ((h.toString() == 'S') || (h.toString() == 'W'))`

Comment: That's Javascript, not C#. Javascript doesn't have ints or doubles, it just has numbers. It also has two equality comparison operators, `==` and `===`. This is true: `(1 == "1")`, this is not `(1 === "1")`. Javascript is an acquired taste

Comment: Using Number(d) on all var's fixes the problem. Thank you. I have been thrown this code to update/fix so lots of learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Number(d) on all var's fixes the problem